# IOError: Decoder Zip Not Found while using mapproxy with mapserver in windows 7 64bit machine

Tags: mapproxy

I am new to GIS technology.  I have configured a map server OSGEO4W.  I am able to render maps using WMS and openlayers. But the rendering is very slow.

For faster rendering I want to use Mapproxy.  I have installed Mapproxy with Python virtual environment.  Mapproxy service is running fine.  I am checking it with the following url "http://"mylocalhost":8080/"
Then, it is showing:

"Welcome to MapProxy 1.5.0"

I have changed the mapproxy.yaml as per the demo application file so that it shows its "demo" application. When I am browsing demo application and rendering map using EPSG:4326 or EPSG:900913 (even when I am using it in my application with openlayers and map file, then also it is showing the the following):

It is showing a blank image.
It is showing the following error on command window:

> File
>   "c:\mapproxy_venv\lib\site-packages\pil-1.1.7-pu2.7-win-amd64.egg\Image.py"
>   line 385, in _getdecoder raise IOError("decoder %s not available" %
>   decoder_names) IOError: decoder zip not available

It means it does not receive "decoder zip".

Please help me to fix this problem.

Thanks

Comment: I will need to see your YAML file in order to help debug this. Would you mind posting? EDIT: From the error, it looks like you are getting a PIL error, not necessarily a MapProxy error. How did you install PIL? Did you use PIP (within your virtualenv) to install it?

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here.

Mapproxy on Windows 7 64-bit. I installed it following the docs:
http://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/install_windows.html

I had to compile PIL, as a binary version was not available for my system. I experienced issues with vcvarsall.bat, but in the end I managed to compile it using the free Windows SDK C/C++ compiler from Microsoft, as explained here:
https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows